# Firebase cannot connect with database after certain time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase latest libraries in my gradle.

When I close the app and open after a few mins, I am able to fetch the uid because the user is not null.

But the database reference is not working and im getting some googleapi gms error. The database security rule is open for all. If I logout and login again it is working fine. Only if the user is logged in and opens the app after sometime this error occurs

What is the solution to this?

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user!= null) {
                uid = user.getUid();
                DatabaseReference mRefregggg;
                mRefregggg = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                mRefregggg.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String abc = dataSnapshot.child("profile/"+uid+"/abc").getValue().toString();
         @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
              };
```

Here's the logcat of the error

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@9b65d04
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@9b65d04
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Here is my gradle dependencies

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
 }


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project level gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
}
```

Here is my database structure

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oaYz.png)

Also, I am including a screenshot from the Tools->Firebase from Android Studio. I connected the app manually by placing the google-services.json file in the project->app folder initially.

[Firebase Android Studio Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLRaB.png)

Comment: can you please show us the code.

Comment: @Nirav - In the code within the mAuthListener when user!=null I am getting uid=user.getUid(); . After that I am using databasereference to get data from db

Comment: can you please show the code for database reference which you were calling after you get uid in which you are getting error.

Comment: Please shouw us your code and the entire error from the logcat. Please responde with @.

Comment: show the code and logcat error in order to get help

Comment: @NiravBhavsar please check the edits

Comment: @AlexMamo Please check the edits

Comment: @GastónSaillén Please check the edits

Comment: can you post your database structure ?

Comment: @VarunDwarkani Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to connect sometimes to the database because you have this line

```
mRefregggg = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

inside your auth listener, so, if sometimes the user is null that instance of the database will not execute and you can't reach your database.

Remove that line from your listener and put tit inside your `onCreate()` method, then you will always initialize your database reference when you are in that activity instead of waiting to see if the user is null or not to initialize.

So it should be done like this:

```
private DatabaseReference mRefregggg;

onCreate() {
super....
mRefregggg = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

yourAuthListener
}
```

for this problem

```
module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

if you are using anonymous login with email and password, check if that is enabled in your Firebase console and check if the device you are executing your app has Android Google Play services >= 9.0.0.

Comment: Having the database ref intialized in the oncreate outside onstatelistener still did not solve my problem

Comment: also, I am not using anonymous login. The emailpass option is enabled and by play servies do u mean the play services auth? If yes, it is 15.0.1

Comment: its best for you to have the reference initialized in your oncreate rather than inside the listener, because sometimes it will not initialize if you need to use it in another place, but i get that you only want people authenticated to post in the database, but that is handled by firebase auth

Comment: is this happening when login or register?

Comment: No. The user is able to register and login. The database ref is working for the first few times. But if the app is closed and opened after lets say 30 minutes, I am getting those error in my logcat. I am toasting the UID and it is getting toasted perfectly.